# What are the lim sups and lim infs of a sequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

What relation, if any, can you state for the lim sups and lim infs of a sequence {an} and one of its subsequences {$a_n$$_k$}?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \{a_{n}\} \leq
\liminf_{k \to \infty} \{a_{n_k}\} \leq
\limsup_{k \to \infty} \{a_{n_k}\} \leq
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \{a_{n}\} 
$$